# sinon - callsArgWith advanced usage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I can use `callsArgWith` to test callbacks, for example:

```
var modelsMock = { 
  Users: {
    findOne: sinon.stub()
  }
};

usersController.__set__({
  'models': modelsMock, 
}); 

//... inside a test:
var user = 'foo';
modelsMock.Users.findOne.callsArgWith(1, true, user);
```

this works just fine when my code is:

```
models.Users.findOne(id, function(err, user) {
   //stuff here.
});
```

but how can I test a callback in the following situation?

```
var user = new models.Users(userData);
user.save(function(err) {
  //I want to test this callback
});
```

Let me know if it is not clear enough and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spy function as the callback itself; it's unrelated to your existing mock.

Let's say you want to test the following function:

```
function createUser(callback) {
  var user = new models.Users(userData);
  user.save(callback);
}
```

In your test, you'd pass it a spy as the callback

```
// inside a test
var spyCallback = sinon.spy(); 
// when
createUser(spyCallback);
// then
assert(spyCallback.calledWith(user));
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I have a "private" method that I cannot spy on (using typescript).

Comment: @PavelSapehin I don't understand your comment, the spy here is passed as callback. If you have a private method that you can't call from a test because it's not visible, that's not related to the original question.